# How to Return the Date Corresponding to the 45th Working Day using Transact SQL in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I already have a function that takes two dates and calculate the number of working days (excluding weekends and observed holidays).  The function is programmed as follows:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fncWorkingDays] 
(
@DATERECD datetime,
@ATTDATE datetime
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE
    @workingDays int,
    @holidays int,
    @weekendDays int

--Determine the number of calendar days
SET @workingDays = DATEDIFF(D, @DATERECD, @ATTDATE);

--Determine the number of holidays
SELECT @holidays = COUNT(ID) FROM ECD.dbo.HOLIDAYCALENDARTABLEDETAILS WHERE HOLIDAYDATE 
BETWEEN @DATERECD AND @ATTDATE AND HCSET=10642;

--Determine the number of weekend days
SET @weekendDays = DATEDIFF(WW, @DATERECD, @ATTDATE) * 2;

--Determine the number of working days
SET @workingDays = @workingDays - @holidays - @weekendDays;

-- Return the result of the function
RETURN @workingDays

END

@workingDays takes the difference between two fields in the database and then subtracts the number of holidays from our holiday table that occur within the date range and finally subtracts the number of weekend days.
```

This function works correctly.  When the function is passed the dates of 11/8/22 and 1/25/23, the return value is 51 working days.

The holiday table contains the following entries for the current calendar year:

```
HCYEAR  HOLIDAYDATE             HOLIDAYDESCRIPTION
2023    2023-01-02 00:00:00.000 NEW YEAR'S DAY
2023    2023-01-16 00:00:00.000 MLK BDAY
2023    2023-02-20 00:00:00.000 WASHINGTON'S BDAY
2023    2023-05-29 00:00:00.000 MEMORIAL DAY
2023    2023-07-04 00:00:00.000 INDEPENDENCE DAY
2023    2023-09-04 00:00:00.000 LABOR DAY
2023    2023-10-09 00:00:00.000 COLUMBUS DAY
2023    2023-11-10 00:00:00.000 VETERAN'S DAY 
2023    2023-11-23 00:00:00.000 THANKSGIVING DAY
2023    2023-12-25 00:00:00.000 CHRISTMAS DAY
2023    2023-06-19 00:00:00.000 juneteenth
```

Question:  We need to know on which date the 45th working day occurs.  In the above example, 1/17/23 would be the correct answer.  This is reflective of observed US Holidays as defined in our holiday table.  I've tried deriving this results through the following code:

```
DateAdd(d, fncWorkingDays(cm.DATERECD, CAST(cd.AttDate as date) ), cm.DateRECD ) as Day45Date
```

The result received is 12/29/22.  Date Received = 11/8/22 while AttDate = 1/25/23.

How would I program the calculation to correctly return the date of the 45th working day?

Comment: It all becomes a lot simpler if you populate a calendar table with a "is working date" flag. This makes adapting to unexpected holidays, etc, very simple (changes to data, not code).

Comment: I just read that you have a calendar table. Please include its full definition, and the definition of the functions you reference.

Comment: If the function returns a sequence of 45 days, can't you just apply a ROW_NUMBER() ordered by date, and then case when rn = 45 then that's your day?

Comment: @MatBailie We actually have a table containing observed holidays.  I've edited my question to include the output for current calendar year.

Comment: It would help if the sample included ALL the holidays between 11/8/22 and 1/25/23.

Comment: Oh, and are you **sure** the correct answer isn't Jan 12 2023?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn  Turns out our holiday table was incorrect.  Christmas was observed on  December 26th last year.  Thanks for bringing this to my attention!!

Comment: Great, that gets me to Jan 13... still a few days off ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help understand this, each paragraph below roughly corresponds to each CTE/query from the provided code sample in order.

First we need to improve on the calendar table, and to do this I start by generating a `digits` table.

Now I can generate a larger series of numbers on the order of the value we need. In this case, I used the digits table+CROSS JOIN technique, where you add another CROSS JOIN for each power of 10 you need.<sup>*</sup> Since we need 45 rows, generating up to 100 should do it. At this point we can also add the generated numbers to the provided starting date to project a base for our final calendar.

Next we remove weekends with `DATEPART()`, and use an exclusion join to also remove holidays via the provided table (though a `NOT EXISTS()` might be faster). We can also  mark the rows that remain with `row_number()`.

Finally, we only want the row marked as `45`.

```
WITH Digits As
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9))nums(d)
), 
FullCalendar As (
    SELECT DATEADD(day, d1.d*10 + d2.d, @DateRecd) theDate
    FROM digits d1
    CROSS JOIN digits d2
),
filteredAndNumbered As (
    SELECT theDate,
        row_number() over (order by theDate) rn
    FROM FullCalendar c
    LEFT JOIN ECD.dbo.HOLIDAYCALENDARTABLEDETAILS hc ON hc.HolidayDate = c.theDate
        AND HCSET=10642
    WHERE DATEPART(dw,theDate) NOT IN (1, 7)
        AND hc.HolidayDate IS NULL
) 
SELECT theDate
FROM filteredAndNumbered
WHERE rn = 45
```

See it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/F2FM_UWE

Note I get a different answer (Jan 13, 2023) than suggested (Jan 17, 2023). I still think **this code** is right, and it's *the question* actually miscounting things. I can show it by slightly [changing up my final query](https://dbfiddle.uk/g3i9sMMz). Now we can easily see each counted date with its day of the week, and it's clear there are no weekend days or holidays included, and no days or holidays skipped. Yet we get all the way to day 45 by Jan 13. Note this is also only off by **one day**, because the 14th and 15th are a weekend and the 16th is a holiday.

Throw in some combination of the Friday after Thanksgiving, Boxing Day, an observed day for New Year's Eve, Hannukah, etc, and it's possible the Holiday table is just incomplete. It could also be the intent is to starting counting with `@DateRecd` as day 0, instead of day 1. But I still think the Jan 13th date shows the accurate calculation based on the info provided.

---

<sup>* Starting in SQL Server 2022, this can be simplified with the new `generate_series()` function.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume HOLIDAYCALENDARTABLEDETAILS contains a list of holidays in column HOLIDAYDATE.

We could do a function like:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fncWorkingDayGet] 
(
@DATERECD datetime,
@WorkingDay INT
)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, 1, @DATERECD) AS start
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, 1, start)
        FROM    CTE c
        WHERE   DATEDIFF(DAY, @DATERECD, DATEADD(DAY, 1, start)) <= @WorkingDay * 10 -- assume americans haven't given up on working altogether
    )
    SELECT  start
    FROM    (
            SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c.start) sort
            ,   start
            FROM    CTE c
            LEFT JOIN HOLIDAYCALENDARTABLEDETAILS hd
                ON  hd.HOLIDAYDATE = c.start
            WHERE   hd.HOLIDAYDATE IS NULL
            AND ((datepart(DW, start) + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7) + 1 NOT IN (6,7) --skip sat/sun
        ) x
    WHERE sort = @WorkingDay
```

Test call:

```sql
select *
from fncWorkingDayGet('20231010', 10) x
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Basically, I generate a list of dates that make sure to encompass most working days and then start counting them, excluding holiday and Saturdays/Sundays.

If you have calendar table you can replace the CTE with it. As others mentioned, it could save you a lot of hassle if you just prepopulate a working-table once instead of relying on functions

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to add the 2022 holidays involved (Thanksgiving and Christmas) to your existing table.

Assuming we have a calendar table:

```
DECLARE @Holidays TABLE (HCYEAR INT, HolidayDate DATE, HolidayDescription VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Holidays (HCYEAR, HolidayDate, HolidayDescription) VALUES
('2023', '2023-01-02 00:00:00.000', 'NEW YEAR''S DAY'),
('2023', '2023-01-16 00:00:00.000', 'MLK BDAY'),
('2023', '2023-02-20 00:00:00.000', 'WASHINGTON''S BDAY'),
('2023', '2023-05-29 00:00:00.000', 'MEMORIAL DAY'),
('2023', '2023-07-04 00:00:00.000', 'INDEPENDENCE DAY'),
('2023', '2023-09-04 00:00:00.000', 'LABOR DAY'),
('2023', '2023-10-09 00:00:00.000', 'COLUMBUS DAY'),
('2023', '2023-11-10 00:00:00.000', 'VETERAN''S DAY '),
('2023', '2023-11-23 00:00:00.000', 'THANKSGIVING DAY'),
('2023', '2023-12-25 00:00:00.000', 'CHRISTMAS DAY'),
('2023', '2023-06-19 00:00:00.000', 'juneteenth'),
/* adding the 2022 holidays */
('2022', '2022-11-24 00:00:00.000', 'THANKSGIVING DAY'),
('2022', '2022-12-26 00:00:00.000', 'CHRISTMAS DAY');
```

In this example we're referencing the TVF `dbo.Calendar`, but any calendar solution should work, as long as it has a flag for week days.

```
SELECT Date, rn, a.HolidayDescription
  FROM (
        SELECT Date, IsWeekDay, h.HolidayDescription, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.Date) AS rn
          FROM Calendar(1,1) c
            LEFT OUTER JOIN @Holidays h
              ON c.Date = h.HolidayDate
           WHERE Date >= '2022-11-08'
             AND c.IsWeekDay = 1 
             AND h.HolidayDate IS NULL 
       ) a
 WHERE a.rn = 45;
```

| Date | rn | HolidayDescription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-12 | 45 |  |